# Connected to network but cannot access Internet

Tags: 18.04, wireless, internet

My friend and I both are having an issue on Ubuntu 18.04; after a recent update, we cannot longer access the internet. It connects to a network, obtains an IP, but cannot get to the internet.

We have tried this on multiple networks that have worked in the past. The only solution we had was temporary and involved boot using recovery.

What did we do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your recent update was on 18.04 , I thought it was no longer possible to update 18.04 , please double check.

Comment: It's got 18.04-LTS, shouldn't that be receiving updates?

Comment: 18.04 LTS still receives updates just fine.  It all depends on what the last updates for the system were when you noticed the connection to the internet stop working.  You can always try booting your system to a previous kernel from the grub menu and see if that works.